# Windows Experience Index Can't Complete Its Run

Tags: windows, windows-experience-index

Windows Experience Index Can't Complete Its Run

WEI starts OK and shows it is accessing...as it runs through its normal cycle, but then quits; it displays an error message stating it could not complete because "the temp file needed to perform the work could not be placed on the disk."

It worked when it was new about 15 months ago.
Now each time I run it the exact same error message is displayed.

Can the app somehow be reinstalled? Or does someone have any other idea how to fix the problem.

Comment: It seems to be a permission problem with it gaining access to your disk

Comment: Is there plenty of free space on your drive(s)?  What drive letters are your drives assigned to use?

Comment: Empty your temporary folder. This is located at `%temp%`. Then try it again, running as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for inconsistencies in windows apps by using

```
sfc /scannow
```

from the command line. see if this fixes the problem.

If this fails to fix the problem check the permissions on this folder and it's sub folders

```
C:\Windows\Performance
```

This is where all the WinSAT/WEI files are stored during the test.

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions on the folder `C:\Windows\Performance\WinSAT`. It's the folder where Windows Experience Index stores its assessment result and where it saves temporary video files to assess decoding speed.

My system has the following permissions:

- **SYSTEM** and **Administrators**

  - Full control over *Subfolders and files*, and
  - Almost all permissions assigned to *This folder only* except:

    - *Full control*,
    - *Delete subfolders and files*,
    - *Change permissions*, and
    - *Take ownership*.
- **TrustedInstaller** has full permissions on *This folder and subfolders*.

---

You can use `WinSAT` command line tool to determine which assessment fails. Most likely, it's *disk* or *media* assessment.

Try running the following commands from elevated Command Prompt:

```
WinSAT media
WinSAT disk
```

You can view the log file in `C:\Windows\Performance\WinSAT\winsat.log`.

Answer (score 0):

If the folder C:\Windows\Performance\ has read only permission attribute set, just remove it ( uncheking it from the Folder properties and apply that change).

That should fix the issue.